# Test prints on the same variable seem to be giving different results

Tags: c++, arrays, stdio

This is a small bit of code being used for Dijkstra's algorithm.  I'm trying to create an array (first_edge) that will tell me the starting index of each "source" node in E which is an array of structs called "Edge" that hold a source node's id#, a destination node's id#, and the distance between the two.

This is just to make it faster to find all of the edges leading out of a given source node.

The test statements I have built into the for loop print out exactly what I would expect them too, based on the input, but the second loop, (for(j = 0; j < 15; j++ ){ code }) prints that all of my first 15 values are just 0.

I can't imagine anything that would cause my code to seemingly give me two different answers for the same question, but that's what it seems to be doing.

```
int* first_edge = new int[23947350];

first_edge[0] = 0;

for(j = 1; j < 58333344; j++) {
  if(E[j].src > E[j-1].src) {
    if(j < 15) {
      //this line prints what i expect it too, which is good
      cout << "First edge updated  " << j << "   " << E[j].src << endl;
    }
    first_edge[E[j].src] = j;
    if(j < 15) {
       cout << "first edge now " << first_edge[E[j].src] << endl;
       cout << "Oh and the index is " << E[j].src << endl;
    } // end if
  } // end if
} // end for

for(j = 0; j < 15; j++) {
// earlier prints verify the correct contents of first_edge, surely this will work!
  cout << "    " << first_edge[j] << "  " << j << endl;
}
```

Some output. I took the liberty of making it less wordy and just giving the values i'm given.

```
((j = 3; E[j].src = 1; first_edge[E[j].src] = 3))  
((j = 5; E[j].src = 2; first_edge[E[j].src] = 5)) 
((j = 8; E[j].src = 3; first_edge[E[j].src] = 8))
```

Since there was some question as to the validity of my concern, I hardcoded first_edge[1] into the earlier loops, and it proved to be 3.  In the later for loop, all values from 0 to 14 of first_edge printed as 0.

Comment: Can you show us the output of your code?  I don't see the relationship of `E[j].src` to `j`.

Comment: i am just printing j to keep track of where im at in the loop, it's not terribly important.

Answer (score 0):

Let's say j = 7.

In the first loop you then print 7 followed by E[7].src.

Then, after updating first_edge[E[7].src], that output is followed by first_edge[E[7].src] and E[7].src.

In the last loop you print first_edge[7] followed by 7.

Is there any reason that you expect all these to print the same?

I can't see it.

Comment: The first print statements show E[j].src (the index for first_edge) to be increasing regularly as i expect it too, from 0 up through 5.

In other words, the first loop confirms for me that something like first_edge[E[7].src] would be valued at say 3, and that E[7].src is 1, so that should mean that first_edge[1] = 3.

The second loop, then, wouldn't line up directly with the earlier statements, but when I get to say, first_edge[1] i should get 3, but instead, first_edge[0 - 14] all equal 0.

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing how the Edge structure is related to `j`, it is impossible to correlate `E[j].src` in relation to `j`. Thus `E[j].src` may not be equal to `j`.

Therefore, `first_edge[E[0].src]` to `first_edge[E[14].src]` may not necessarily be the first 15 of `first_edge`, `first_edge[0]` to `first_edge[14]`.

Comment: E[j].src definitely doesn't equal j, nor do I want it to.  E[j].src would be the index in first_edge, that will store the location that the same value for E[j].src appears at, because E[j].src will have several repeated values in order (its sorted).  first_edge helps me find where a particular source id# first appears in E faster.